# htaccess redirect to subdomain based on query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I searched for similar questions but none of them was applicable to my situation.

What I need to do is redirect from old url's that have specific query string: `option=com_virtuemart` to a subdomain : `http://parts.domain.com`

Tried bunch of rules and conds but haven't achieved right redirection. It was always redirecting me to `http://parts.domain.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart`

Some of the rules I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_virtuemart(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://parts.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_virtuemart(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule http://parts.domain.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

And like 50 other rules. What mistakes I'm doing here?

Comment: *"It was always redirecting me to `http://parts.domain.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart`"* Isn't that what you wanted?...

Comment: Nope, what I want is `http://parts.domain.com` without the rest of QS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to combine your rules.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_virtuemart(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://parts.domain.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

In the second example, you had not provided the regular expression to match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but again it strangely redirects to `http://parts.domain.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart`

Comment: @Zota In that case, you should probably clear your cache. If no other rules are present in .htaccess, this should work fine.

Comment: Oops, I constantly cleared cache under firefox, even 'hard clear' but somehow it didn't clear. After your suggestion I tried it with IE and your rules worked just fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the `parts.domain.com` root, then you can do this in your .htaccess.

This works for me you don't really need a capture group you can use `^`. Also make sure you clear your cache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_virtuemart(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://parts.domain.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Or you could do something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /+(index\.php)?\?option=com_virtuemart [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://parts.domain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I'm actually under `http://www.domain.com` that's the main site where I need to take care of old urls

Comment: The rules are fine either way. As I initially said in my answer. You should clear your cache as the rules do work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, somehow I missed your suggestion to clear cache... Anyway all is well now :)